# Apple pencil tap gesture recognizing problem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented the `UIPencilInteractionDelegate` to detect apple pencil double tap as follows.

```
UIPencilInteraction *pencilInteraction = [[UIPencilInteraction alloc] init];
pencilInteraction.delegate = self;
[self.view addInteraction:pencilInteraction];
```

delegate method implementation

```
- (void)pencilInteractionDidTap:(UIPencilInteraction *)interaction{
    NSLog(@"Detected");
}
```

However cannot detect the double tap gesture with above implementation. What will be the mistake?

Comment: Solved. Problem is in my view controller.

Comment: I encounter the same problem, what did you do in your view controller to fix it ?